Use my auxiliar clock in RTP in VxWorks 7
I'm using the auxiliar clock in my Kernel layer with clock_gettime.
But now i want to use it in my RTP but i can't. I have been reading that i have to do a dynamic call to use it, I have been trying but i don't really know how to do it.
Has anyone ever done it?
I've been trying to call it with a dynamic call making a system call handler and his header, but i didn't get it. If there any better solution it will help to me. This is the function that i have in my dkm.c, and i want to call it in my rtp.c
STATUS test_gettime
(
clockid_t clockId  /* CLOCK_REALTIME (0) or CLOCK_MONOTONIC (1) */
)
{
unsigned ix;
#define NTS 10
struct timespec tss[NTS];
for (ix = 0; ix < NTS; ++ix)
    {
    if (clock_gettime (clockId, &tss[ix]) != OK)
        {
        perror ("clock_gettime");
        return ERROR;
        }
    }

for (ix = 0; ix < NTS; ++ix)
    {
    struct timespec diff;
    printf ("%2u:  %9lu.%09ld ", ix, tss[ix].tv_sec, tss[ix].tv_nsec);
    if (ix == 0)
        {
        printf ("\n");
        continue;
        }
    diff = tss[ix];
    TV_SUB (diff, tss[ix -1]);
    printf (" diff: %9lu.%09ld\n", diff.tv_sec, diff.tv_nsec);
    }

return OK;
}

